# iOS Rotate label if too long

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

In the iPhone music player or on the lockscreen when you double-press the home button, if the title, author, or album name of the track is too long for displaying, the text starts to move, so that the entire text can be read eventually.

How can I achieve this? Is there any public API for this, or do I have to make it myself?

(Sorry if this was asked already or it is trivial, I didn't know how to describe it to google)

Comment: The term you need is "marquee" (I don't know why that is the word!). Try this: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/marqueelabel

Comment: Thanks for starting me with the word. Make it an answer?

Comment: Ok, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you need is "marquee" (I don't know why that is the word, but the HTML effect is also called this!).

There are a number of open source implementations around, here's one example:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/marqueelabel

Answer (score 0):

Music Controls does exactly what you want. http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.phoenix.pandoracontrols

It'll cost you five bucks though, and you need to be jailbroken.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do so from my own app.